# unable to start nodemanager in hadoop2.8.0 windows setup

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am getting below error while starting yarn node-manager in windows10

```
Yarn resource manager is running. Could anyone suggest how this issue can be fixed! Hadoop version is 2.8.0
        19/10/30 16:53:47 INFO nodemanager.NodeManager: STARTUP_MSG:
        /************************************************************
        STARTUP_MSG: Starting NodeManager
        STARTUP_MSG:   user = user1
        STARTUP_MSG:   host = 1.1.1.1
        STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
        STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.8.0
        STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = 
        STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 91f2b7a13d1e97be65db92ddabc627cc29ac0009; compiled by 'jdu' on 2017-03-17T04:12Z
        STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.8.0_231
        ************************************************************/
        19/10/30 16:53:52 INFO nodemanager.NodeManager: Node Manager health check script is not available or doesn't have execute permission, so not starting the node health script runner.
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl$ContainerEventDispatcher
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.ApplicationEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl$ApplicationEventDispatcher
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.event.LocalizationEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServicesEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainersLauncherEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainersLauncher
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.ContainerManagerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManagerEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system started
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeHealthCheckerService failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
        java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:636)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:86)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:630)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:861)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:625)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.primitiveMkdir(FileSystem.java:1071)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DelegateToFileSystem.mkdir(DelegateToFileSystem.java:177)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFs.mkdir(FilterFs.java:206)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$4.next(FileContext.java:738)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$4.next(FileContext.java:734)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.mkdir(FileContext.java:734)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createDir(DirectoryCollection.java:478)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createDir(DirectoryCollection.java:476)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createDir(DirectoryCollection.java:476)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createDir(DirectoryCollection.java:476)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createDir(DirectoryCollection.java:476)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createNonExistentDirs(DirectoryCollection.java:275)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.serviceInit(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:206)
                at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
                at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeHealthCheckerService.serviceInit(NodeHealthCheckerService.java:50)
                at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
                at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:357)
                at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:636)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:684)        
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NodeManager metrics system...
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system stopped.
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system shutdown complete.
        19/10/30 16:53:53 FATAL nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
        java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:636)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:86)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:630)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:861)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:625)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.primitiveMkdir(FileSystem.java:1071)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DelegateToFileSystem.mkdir(DelegateToFileSystem.java:177)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFs.mkdir(FilterFs.java:206)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$4.next(FileContext.java:738)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$4.next(FileContext.java:734)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.mkdir(FileContext.java:734)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createDir(DirectoryCollection.java:478)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createDir(DirectoryCollection.java:476)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createDir(DirectoryCollection.java:476)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createDir(DirectoryCollection.java:476)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createDir(DirectoryCollection.java:476)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DirectoryCollection.createNonExistentDirs(DirectoryCollection.java:275)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LocalDirsHandlerService.serviceInit(LocalDirsHandlerService.java:206)
                at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
                at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeHealthCheckerService.serviceInit(NodeHealthCheckerService.java:50)
                at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
                at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:357)
                at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:636)
                at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:684)
        19/10/30 16:53:53 INFO nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
        /************************************************************
        SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at 1.1.1.1
        ************************************************************/
```